# What’s the missing number? And why?

Tags: machine-learning

So there is a box, In this box there are two small boxes up and down , upper box is “x” and lower box is “y” , and there are two other numbers without boxes so left one is “l” and right one is “r”. So there will be four boxes , 1st box x is 2, y is 14, l is 7 & r is 16. 2nd box x is 4, y is 6 , l is 12 , r is 8. 3rd box x is 5, y is 8, l is 16 & r is 10. 4th box x is 5, y is 9, l is 9 and I want you to find what’s the number for r in 4th box.
[image]

Comment: I'm closing this question because it is not a question about Artificial Intelligence, and therefore not on-topic for this site.